# Having a hard time Figuring out a Function in C

Tags: c, unix

I'm having a hard time walking through this function to figure out what exactly it is doing.

```
int f2(char *s) {
  char *p;
  for (p = s; *p != ’\0’; p++)
  ;
    for (--p; p >= s && (*p < ’0’ || *p > ’9’); p--)
  ;
      if (p < s)
        return 1;
      while (p >= s && *p >= ’0’ && *p <= ’9’) {
        if (*p == ’9’)
          *p = ’0’;
        else {
          (*p)++;
          return 0;
        }
      p--;
      }
    if (p >= s && *p == ’ ’) {
      *p = ’1’;
      return 0;
    }
  return 1;
}
```

I've tried walking through it with the GDB debugger, but to no avail. I think my biggest issue currently is not being sure what sort of input to test it with.

Comment: do you know what the first `for` loop does?

Comment: Broad Scope, no. However I under stand that it sets the memory address of pointer p to that of the input point s. As long as the value held at this memory address isn't null, you move up a memory address.

Comment: then you should've said yes! That's exactly what it's doing. It advances `p` one `char` at a time until it is pointing to the `NUL` terminator of the `s` string. The second `for` loop initializes `p` to one less (so it's now pointing to the last `char` of `s`.

Comment: Dont give up on gdb yet. Put a breakpoint at `if (p<s)` and print out `p`. If you don't understand how ti got there, then give the `for` loop a body, ie `for (--p; p >= s && (*p < ’0’ || *p > ’9’); p--) { int a = 3; }` so you can step through it one iteration at a time (maybe you can as is, I don't debug many body-less loops). Just make sure to compile with optimizations turned off, `gcc -O0 ... `

Comment: `for (p = s; *p != ’\0’; p++)` is not valid C code.  Cut n Paste error?  Post true code.

Comment: `int f2(char *s) {
  char *p;
  for (p = s; *p != '\0'; p++)
  ;
    for (--p;...` is undefined behavior with `f2("")`.

Comment: The problem with the lines like `for (p = s; *p != ’\0’; p++)` is that the quote used is U+2019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK instead of U+0027, the ASCII single quote.  That suggests you used a word processor instead of a programming editor at some point.  Fix the quotes to ASCII and that line is OK.  Your loop with `for (--p; p >= s; p--)` tries to generate the address before the start of `s`, which may not be valid.  One beyond the end of the array is required to be valid (but not readable); one before is not required to be valid.  You should think about `for ( ; p-- > s /* && … */; )`.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the code, you can see it's comparing things against `'0'`, `'9'`, and `' '`. So, for "what sort of input to test it with", try feeding it strings of different numbers, sometimes with spaces between them and sometimes not. Maybe also try putting a letter in one.

`"120973628029"`
`"9375906 72010"`
`"0826"`
`"40726a591"`
and such.

Comment: Thanks, and will do! Prior, I had only been putting in letters

Comment: @SamBarefoot Note I just added a sentence to the start of my answer to explain my reasoning. (If this answer solves your problem, please use the "accept" button.)

Comment: When testing, make sure you do not pass string literals to the function; they're likely to cause your program to crash.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler why?

Comment: @Jesin: often, string literals are stored in readonly memory, so the program will crash when you try to modify it.

Comment: Note that strings like `a9`, `ab99`, and `alpaca999` are informative.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You are correct. Both of these are good points.